# Enhanced animation

Tags: beamer, foreach, animate, tikz-pic

I started with a simple animation and tried in the second step to improve it.

In the second frame I included a long horizontal rectangle, filled by white squares (foreach loop).

Is there a way to save ressources by excluding the "static" part outside the aninmation e.g. the black square or the horizontal rectangle with the white squares?

Further I would like to know if there is a better approach for placing the controls and the animation exactly where I want in a frame.

In the last step I would like to move the red vertical line along the time axis syncrhonized to the blinking. What is the best way to approach this?

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Simple Flash Example}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
                Text for signal description and other explanations.
                
                Here a simple blink animation is expected, as long as the pseudo notes are copied to each new picture it works fine.
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
                \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,scale=.66]{2}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \node at (-6,0) {}; %playing with pseudo notes feels ineffctive, is there a simpler approach for correct placing of animatation and/or controls (general approach / within a column)?
                        \node at (4,0) {};
                        \node[draw=black, %black rectangle (white circle will appear)
                        fill=black,
                        minimum width=1cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (-1,1) {};
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \newframe
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \node at (-6,0) {};
                        \node at (4,0) {};
                        \node[draw=black,
                        fill=black,
                        minimum width=1cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (-1,1) {};
                        \node[circle,draw,fill=white] (c) at (-1,1){}; %white Circle
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{animateinline}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame} 
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Complex Flash Example}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
                Text for signal description and other explanations. 
                
                The red vertikal line now should move sychronized with the blinking, what is the best way to realise this? And how could i add a timeline below the lower rectangle with e.g. seconds?
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
                \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,scale=.66]{2}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \node[draw=black, %black rectangle (white circle will appear)
                        fill=black,
                        minimum width=1cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (-1,1) {};
                        
                        \node[draw=black, %long rectangle
                        fill=black,
                        minimum width=6.0cm,
                        minimum height=0.5cm] at (-1,-1) {};
                        
                        \foreach \x in {-3.9,-3.4,...,1.9}
                        {
                            \node[draw=black,  
                            fill=white,
                            minimum width=0.5,
                            minimum height=0.5cm] at (\x,-1.) {}; %white rectangles
                        }
                            
                        \draw [line width=0.4mm,  red] (-4.05,-0.75) -- (-4.05,-1.25) node [right]{}; %red vertical line
                        
                        \foreach \x in {-4,-3.5,...,2} %timeline
                        {
                            \draw[shift={(\x,-1.5)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
                        }
                        \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,6} %timeline numbers
                        {
                        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{int(\x * 2)};
                        \draw[shift={({\x - 4},-1.5)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
                        {$\y$};
                        }
                        
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \newframe
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \node[draw=black,
                        fill=black,
                        minimum width=1cm,
                        minimum height=1cm] at (-1,1) {}; %black square
                        
                        \node[draw=black, 
                        fill=black,
                        minimum width=6.0cm,
                        minimum height=0.5cm] at (-1,-1) {}; %long rectangle
                        
                        \foreach \x in {-3.9,-3.4,...,1.9}
                            {
                            \node[draw=black,  
                            fill=white,
                            minimum width=0.5,
                            minimum height=0.5cm] at (\x,-1.) {}; %white rectangles
                            }
                        
                        \node[circle,draw,fill=white] (c) at (-1,1){}; %white Circle 
                            
                        \draw [line width=0.4mm,  red] (-4.05,-0.75) -- (-4.05,-1.25) node [right]{}; %red vertical line
                        
                        \foreach \x in {-4,-3.5,...,2} %timeline
                        {
                            \draw[shift={(\x,-1.5)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
                        }
                        \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,6} %timeline numbers
                        {
                            \pgfmathsetmacro\y{int(\x * 2)}; %I want only full seconds
                            \draw[shift={({\x - 4},-1.5)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
                            {$\y$};
                        }
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{animateinline}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've added the output of the second frame for better explanation:
[image: 2.nd frame, timeline problem solved meanwhile]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static parts can indeed be typeset once and referenced in multiple frames; see the `timeline` option of `animate`. However, this adds some overhead and may not be worth it in terms of final PDF file size. (Therefore, we don't do this here.)

There are a few options available that allow you to adjust control button size, colour, opacity and alignment, as well as to select only a subset of buttons. See the `animate` manual for details. The whole animation is centred within the right column using `\centering`. The space occupied by the animation is determined by the animation widget only. The base line of the animation is the lower edge of the widget. Controls may overlap neighbouring text.

The primary purpose of TikZ nodes is the placement of text labels in a graphic rather than drawing geometrical shapes. Node shapes are just a means to embellish text labels. For the sake of precision, I use the dedicated drawing commands that TikZ provides.

A smooth, synchronous movement of the red time indicator requires a higher frame rate and some more animation frames. To toggle the visibility of the white dot, I am evaluating "frame number `\i`" modulo "16". 16 frames is one second which is one off/on cycle.

(Click the image to see the animation)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Simple Flash Example}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        Text for signal description and other explanations.
        
        Here is simple blink animation, well centred (\verb+\centering+) within the right column.
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}\centering
        \begin{animateinline}[controls={play,stop,step},loop]{2}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
            \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
          \end{tikzpicture}
          \newframe
          \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
            \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
            \fill[white] (0.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.2];
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{animateinline}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame} 
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Complex Flash Example}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        Text for signal description and other explanations. 
        
        The red vertical line now moves synchronously with the blinking.
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}\centering
        \begin{animateinline}[controls={play,stop,step},loop]{16}
          \multiframe{192}{i=0+1,rline=-3+0.03125}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
              \fill (-0.5,0) rectangle (0.5,1);

              \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\i,16))} % modulo
              \ifnum\pgfmathresult<8\else
                \fill[white] (0,0.5) circle [radius=0.2];
              \fi

              \filldraw (-3,-1) rectangle (3,-0.5);
              \foreach \x in {-2.75,-2.25,...,2.75} {
                \fill[white] (\x,-1) rectangle ++(0.25,0.5);
              }  
              % time indicator
              \draw [thick, red] (\rline,-1) -- ++(0,0.5);

              \foreach \x in {-3,-2.5,...,3} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\mylabel{int(6+2*\x)}
                \node [anchor=north, at={(\x,-1)}] {\tiny\mylabel};
              }  
            \end{tikzpicture}
          }
        \end{animateinline}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

A non-isochronous signal example, as requested in the comments, can be built by splitting up the animation into multiple sections using multiple `\multiframe` blocks put in a row. The number of loops and the initial values of the parameters `i` and `rline` need to be adjusted for each `\multiframe` block.

[image]

Instead of pkg `animate`'s `timeline` feature, this extended example makes use of package `xsavebox` in order to avoid code replication, to reduce compilation time and to get a somewhat smaller PDF output file. The static background image is typeset and saved in an `xlrbox` once, and then inserted in every frame of the animation using a TikZ node:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[dvisvgm,buttonsize=1ex]{animate}
%\usepackage[dvisvgm]{xsavebox}
\usepackage[buttonsize=1ex]{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}\sffamily
  % background graphics
  \begin{xlrbox}{BgImg}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
      \useasboundingbox (-3.2,-1.4) rectangle (3.2,1.1);

      \fill (-0.5,0) rectangle (0.5,1);

      \filldraw (-3,-1) rectangle (3,-0.5);
      \foreach \x in {-2.5625,-2.0625,-1.5625} {
        \fill[white] (\x,-1) rectangle ++(0.0625,0.5);
      }  
      \fill[white] (-1.0,-1) rectangle ++(1.0,0.5);

      \foreach \x in {-3,-2.5,...,3} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mylabel{int(6+2*\x)}
        \node [anchor=north, at={(\x,-1)}] {\tiny\mylabel};
      }  
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{xlrbox}%
  % animation
  \begin{animateinline}[controls={play,stop,step},loop]{16}
    % 3 short flashes of 1/8 s length
    \multiframe{48}{i=0+1,rline=-3+0.03125}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
        % insert BG image
        \node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west, at={(-3.2,-1.4)}] {\theBgImg};

        \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\i,16))} % modulo
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult<14\else
          \fill[white] (0,0.5) circle [radius=0.2]; % flash
        \fi

        \draw [thick, red] (\rline,-1) -- ++(0,0.5); % time indicator
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \newframe
    % 1 s of rest
    \multiframe{16}{i=48+1,rline=-1.5+0.03125}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
        \node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west, at={(-3.2,-1.4)}] {\theBgImg};
        \draw [thick, red] (\rline,-1) -- ++(0,0.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \newframe
    % 2 s of light "on"
    \multiframe{32}{i=64+1,rline=-1+0.03125}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
        \node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west, at={(-3.2,-1.4)}] {\theBgImg};

        \fill[white] (0,0.5) circle [radius=0.2];
        \draw [thick, red] (\rline,-1) -- ++(0,0.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \newframe
    % 6 s of rest
    \multiframe{96}{i=96+1,rline=0.0+0.03125}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.66]
        \node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west, at={(-3.2,-1.4)}] {\theBgImg};
        \draw [thick, red] (\rline,-1) -- ++(0,0.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

In order to build the SVG version, option `dvisvgm` needs to be added for `animate` and `xsavebox`:

```latex
\usepackage[dvisvgm,buttonsize=1ex]{animate}
\usepackage[dvisvgm]{xsavebox}
```

The SVG is then produced with

```bash
dvilualatex example
dvilualatex example
dvisvgm --exact --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 example
```

For best performance, the animated SVG should be opened in Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I'm glad the question is answered meanwhile, i went through some other examples and would have try to solve it by \addtocounter. Also slowly I start to realise, that \foreach can be interpreted nearly literally ;)

Comment: The example above will work good for isochronous signals. If I now would have a signal with 3 Flashes, followed by a blink (e.g. 2s), followed by no signal for ~ 7 seconds, I guess the better approach would be the timeline option, am I right?

Comment: I realised, that the red line in the answer needs a little bit more time to pass from 0 to 12, roughly 13 seconds, is this due to the parallel flashing animation?

Comment: Do you want to have different sections in your animation? You may produce them with several `\multiframe` blocks in a row. As for the speed, which PDF viewer are you using? The example with 16 FPS and a total of 192 frames should exactly take 12 seconds to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, now I am totally confused. If i run your linked example above, it takes 13 seconds, if I test the genarted pdf file on my Windows computer with Acrobat Reader DC (32-bit) it needs only 10 seconds. Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: The built-in timer of Acrobat might be in-accurate. In the past, I have also had the impression of it running too fast. The linked SVG version takes exactly 12 s in Chromium. Firefox is slower which is due to its less performing rendering engine. You may add `measure` to the `animateinline` options which prints the frame rate to the JavaScript console and try to play with the frame rate.

Comment: Good hint with Chromium and Firefox, I rechecked and get with Chromium exactly 12 seconds. The measurements where not 100% accurate, I did them with a stop watch, for detection of a 1 to 2 second delta for a time range of 12 seconds this is precise enough. In the next step i will have to check how to produce svg files instead of pdf and give the advice to use chromium if someone else than me will use the presentation.

Comment: @Arrow : I added an extended example with flashes and rests of varying length. Note that this is not related to the `timeline` feature of animate in the first place. An alternative solution is used to save compilation time, code lines and output file size, based on pkg `xsavebox`. Also instructions for making the SVG are given.

Comment: Thank you, with that knowledge every signal combination I need can be created, the rest is only adaptation. Once the tex live installation is done I will try out the options regarding SVG, at the current installation speed it will happen most likely tomorrow. Regarding timeline: It was only a question.